# nginx basic auth backed on server

Tags: nginx, basic-authentication

I know nginx provide a way to login using basic authentication (with a password file). I wanted to know if there is a way to delegate the authentication to a dedicated server.

Here is the process I want to pursue :
 - The user try to access to the nginx server without auth.
 - Nginx ask for username and password.
 - Nginx request the dedicated server with the provided credentials.
 - If ok, nginx create a new basic auth for the user, and let the user pass in.

Thank you

Comment: I have never used it, but there is the [auth request module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html).

Comment: @Richard Smith : I think it might be the good answer. I suggest you to answer with your link, and I will validate it. Thank you !